# I am attempting to parse a file which does not have much consistency and grab the user id's, first and last name

Tags: c#, list, parsing, dictionary

I am attempting to parse a file which does not have much consistency and grab the user id's, first and last name.

Some of the user id's have no name and are presented as "NOT FOUND". Some have varying number of items per line, hence the multiple if/else if/ blocks.

I have a dictionary of user ids as the key and an struct object which holds the first name and last name as the value. Here is the majority of my code, I would like to add a single object(first and last name) to each dictionary key(user id), but it is currently adding the entire files worth of first and last names to each key(user id).

I have the dictionary.add inside the while loop so I would think it would add them to the dictionary correctly. What am I doing wrong?

And if I'm incorrectly printing out the key and list values please tell me.

EDITED: Fixed the multiple printing issue thanks to "SACH". My other issue now is parsing. The file itself has sensitive info so i'll do my best to provide something similar to an example.

```
l User_ID SECTION(header)                                                                                                                               
  USER_ID                 text     USER_ID     L_Name F_Name some_digits                                                                                  
                          another line or two of unimportant info



l USER_ID SECTION(header)                                                                                                                               
  USER_ID                 text  letter  USER_ID   L_Name M_Name F_Name                                                                                        
                          more lines of unimportant info
```

My issue is that this is not the standard for all the entries in the file. And if I'm not sure what text to expect how can I consistently get the Name

I have no issues getting the ID but with inconsistent entries, some of the names I grab are incorrect. Is there a way to grab the Name without knowing its exact location or string?

```
    public static void read_file() {

        //variable declaration
        string user_id = "*"; 
        string file_path = @"c:\users\blah\blah";
        string line_of_text;

        List<full_name> Name = new List<full_name>();

        //define dictionary for user id, last name, first name
        Dictionary<string, List<full_name>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<full_name>>();

        var filestream = new System.IO.FileStream(file_path,
                                 System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                 System.IO.FileAccess.Read,
                                 System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filestream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 128);


        //loop through reading text file
        while ((line_of_text = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            string[] temp = line_of_text.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


            //check if first line (begins with 'l')
            //if first line, add first and last name to list Name
            int pos = Array.IndexOf(temp, "l");
            if (pos > -1)
            {
                user_id = temp[1];
                line_of_text = file.ReadLine();
                string[] line2 = line_of_text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                int pos2 = Array.IndexOf(line2, "NOT");
                if (pos2 > -1) {
                    Name.Add(new full_name()
                    {
                        f_name = "NOT",
                        l_name = "FOUND"
                    });
                }

                else if (line2.Length == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("F: {0}, L: {1}", line2[3], line2[2]);
                    Name.Add(new full_name()
                    {
                        f_name = line2[3],
                        l_name = line2[2]
                    });
                }
                else if (line2.Length == 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("F: {0}, L: {1}", line2[5], line2[4]);
                    Name.Add(new full_name()
                    {
                        f_name = line2[5],
                        l_name = line2[4]
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("F: {0}, L: {1}", line2[4], line2[3]);
                    Name.Add(new full_name()
                    {
                        f_name = line2[4],
                        l_name = line2[3]
                    });
                }
            }




            if (!dict.ContainsKey(user_id))
            {
                dict.Add(user_id, Name);
            }
        }
        int k = 1;
        int m = 1;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<full_name>> kvp in dict){
            foreach( full_name entry in Name){
                Console.WriteLine("{0}  ID: {1}  Last Name: {2}  First Name: {3}", k, kvp.Key, entry.l_name, entry.f_name);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my struct:

```
struct full_name {
    public string f_name;
    public string l_name;
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide some *examples* of the *file(s)* you have to parse (and the desired outcome)?

Comment: Yeah, we would need to see an example of the data if there's any hope of getting an answer to your question.

Comment: Need to see sample of text files.  Have been parsing text files for over 40 years.  They are always hard to parse especially if humans do the typing.

Comment: Edited my question to include example of text in file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `List<full_name> Name` is defined and instantiated outside the loop where you read your file.

Then inside the loop, every time you read a line you add a record to `Name`, and before the end of the loop you add `Name` to your `dict`, so as your loop progresses your `Name` list grows.

What you need to do is create one `Name` instance (instead of a list) inside the loop every time, and then add it to the dictionary.

```
while ((line_of_text = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Stuff
    full_name name = new full_name();
    if (pos > -1)
    {
        ...
        name.f_name = "NOT";
        name.l_name = "FOUND";
    }

    // Other if statements

    if (!dict.ContainsKey(user_id))
    {
        dict.Add(user_id, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I was over complicating things for no reason.

Comment: @JordanD you're welcome. Please consider marking the answer 'accepted' if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`List<full_name> Name = new List<full_name>();`  is declared at function level. Declare it inside the loop. It keeps appending to the function level list and keeps adding that to every user id.